# sklearn package cannot find modules

Tags: python-2.7, module, scikit-learn, package

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import imputation
```

returns

ImportError: No module named preprocessing

It's there. I can see it.
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing

I can "import sklearn" just fine, but it cannot find any modules, not just preprocessing.

Why can't sklearn find it's modules?  I have scipy & numpy installed on python2.7. Reinstalling didn't help. I'm not using Anaconda.

Comment: what version of sklearn, scipy, and numpy do you have installed?

Comment: How are you calling the above line? From terminal? Are you sure that terminal has the same version of python?

Comment: Wierd, sklearn says version 0.0, scipy is 1.0.0, numpy is 1.13.1,  I am writing into the Atom text editor.   I tried 'pip install sklearn -- upgrade'  but it's telling me it's up to date, so I'm not sure what is going on with that version #.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if this is an old question, for reference I leave the following which should do the trick.

> pip install -U scikit-learn